# How to know if module is loaded on any process of system? C#

Tags: c#, process, module

So... someone know how to make it?

I was thinking in something like:

```
    private bool IsModuleLoaded(String ModuleName)
    {
        bool loaded = false;
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        ProcessModule myProcessModule = null;
        ProcessModuleCollection myProcessModuleCollection;

        for (int i = 0; i < processes.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                myProcessModuleCollection = processes[i].Modules;

                for (int j = 0; j < myProcessModuleCollection.Count; j++)
                {
                    myProcessModule = myProcessModuleCollection[j];

                    if (myProcessModule.ModuleName.Contains(ModuleName))
                    {
                        loaded = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch { loaded = false; }
        }

        return loaded;
    }
```

But it doesn't works, because everytime returns true. Even if the module is not loaded in the memory of any process.

Thanks in advance!.

FIXED CODE:

```
    private bool IsModuleLoaded(String ModuleName)
    {
        bool loaded = false;
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        ProcessModule myProcessModule = null;
        ProcessModuleCollection myProcessModuleCollection;

        for (int i = 0; i < processes.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                myProcessModuleCollection = processes[i].Modules;

                for (int j = 0; j < myProcessModuleCollection.Count; j++)
                {
                    myProcessModule = myProcessModuleCollection[j];

                    if (myProcessModule.ModuleName.Contains(ModuleName))
                    {
                        loaded = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { loaded = false; }
            if (loaded)
                break;
        }

        return loaded;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not loaded? Maybe visual studio loaded it :) When you get a hit in this code, output the name of the process, then check using some external tool like process explorer.

Comment: @mmix: Dude, i have modified the code, now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN the [Process.Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.modules.aspx) property contains the modules that have been already *loaded*. So if a module is not present in the *Modules* collection, it is not loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i debug the code and found the bug, now is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always use the linq to help you with this, it will break out as soon as it hits a name

```
    private bool IsModuleLoaded2(String ModuleName)
    {
        var q = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                from m in p.Modules.OfType<ProcessModule>()
                select m;
        return q.Any(pm => pm.ModuleName.Contains(ModuleName));
    }
```

Also, keep in mind that if you run on 64bit platform you MUST run this inside 64bit process. A 32 bit process cannot access 64 bit process's bits and pieces including a module list. I see that you are catching an exception which is probably the one I speak of, making your (and above) code invalid as it will not enumerate all processes.